# Using free fonts for logos

Tags: typography, copyright, legal

I want a typography logo for an application. If I use free fonts for that, can I just use them directly without mentioning the creator of the free font, or without linking the page where I download them? Or do I have to?

Comment: Depends on the licence and the applicable law in the territory concerned, neither of which you have stated. (In the UK, using a font does not infringe its copyright. Making an unlicensed copy of the font file does, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each font should have a licence that tells you exactly what you can or cannot do without it. Some require that you give them attribution, some require that you buy a licence if it's going to be used for commercial work. If you are unsure about the licence, contact the author of the font.

Answer (score 0):

Spiral is right, you have to read the licence in order to see how you can use the font for free. I'm also a logo designer and when I need a free font for some commercial work I like to use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ - a great collection of free fonts that can be used for commercial purposes.

Cheers!